# Can I use a custom query within a derived column transformation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am reading a csv file into several parent-child database tables.

I need to add 2 derived columns (Id and Reference) to my inputs. These must be based on a value from an existing table in the database - Sync. I want to get the Id value (an integer), use it to construct a reference number, and then increment the value ready for the next input row. Id and Reference are unique keys in the destination table.

In tsql I would do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @ObjectId = value 
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[Sync] 
WHERE Name='Employee'               
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[Sync] SET value=value+1 WHERE name='Employee'  

SELECT @Reference = 'EMP' + cast(value AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Then Object Id and Reference should be used as derived columns.

I don't know how to do this in SSIS - can I do it directly in Derived column Transformation Editor? If not, which component do I use?

Comment: To better understand, you are trying to add the primary key trough a derived column, is that correct? How about using the [IDENTITY Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) in your table so the PK gets generated automaticly?

Comment: Because I need to base the reference on the id as shown above.

Comment: Your approach will not work as SSIS processes rows in batches.  Each row hits each transformation together with thousands of others, so whatever you try they will all get the same value.  You should just let SQL manage this using the IDENTITY property as Eli suggested.